# is it possible to set a field in drupal to some value by using nodeapi

Tags: drupal

So I have this field named `field_movie_cast_count` this is a field of a content named `movie` so what I want is that whenever the movie is updated (like I add another cast member) the `field_movie_cast_count` field would be updated too. I have successfully done it using this code:

```
function count_cast_nodeapi(&$node, $op) {
    $id = $node->nid;
    if($op == 'update' && $node->type == 'movie')  {
        $count=count($node->field_movie_cast);
        $q = db_query("update content_type_movie set field_movie_cast_count_value = '$count' WHERE nid = '$id'");
    }
}
```

Now, my boss told me that I should not use query. So, how do I achieve this by not using a database query?

is it not possible to just set field_movie_cast_count[]['value']=$count? i tried this code it doesnt work. lol

OR SHOULD I REPHRASE THE QUESTION is there any other way of displaying the count cast? aside from my way? cause maybe i did not understand my boss right.

Comment: _"Now, my boss told me that I should not use query"_ Sounds like your boss knows exactly what he wants, have you asked him how to do it?

Comment: nope. hes the strict type of boss. so i just nod everytime he wants something to be done. But is it possible? he's a web developer too so i know he knows what he wants.

Comment: Sorry, thought db_update would do the trick but I can't find it in D6. I was sure it was there... perhaps in some contrib module :(. Here's a link to the D6 abstraction layer api: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.inc/group/database/6

Comment: i dont see anything here  that can help my problem @span. :(

Comment: Me neither unfortunately. Looking at the earlier comments here I'm starting to think it's not possible :/. hook_nodeapi has some interesting things but they all have to do with what happends after an insert/update, not before. I'm afraid I can't help you :(

Comment: can you think of any other way of displaying the count cast? using nodeapi? it sure will involve a query but different from my code? im starting to hate my boss. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_nodeapi()` has a `presave` operation which is invoked just before the node (and field data) is committed to the database. The definition of the operation is:

> The node passed validation and is about to be saved. Modules may use this to make changes to the node before it is saved to the database.

You can use it to update a field value, without resorting to hitting the database manually (which will be overwritten anyway) like so:

```
function MYMODULE_nodeapi(&$node, $op) {
  if ($op == 'presave' && $node->type == 'movie') {
    $node->field_movie_cast_count[0]['value'] = count($node->field_movie_cast);
  }
}
```

Comment: you sir is a genius! i knew that presave is the key to my problem but i cant figure out what presave means or what does it do. You clarified it for me. THANKS A LOT! i hope you win a lottery or something